# Defining multiple objects based on size of two lists (python)

Tags: python, list, object, multiple-instances

I am trying to find a way of creating objects based on the size of two lists. I have to create an object for each combination of indices of the two lists, i.e. if both lists is of the length 3, 9 new objects should be created and defined.

The lists can be of rather large lengths and it would make the script a lot nicer if I did not have to use an if loop to go through all possible combinations.

A first I thought I could do the following:

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2):
        Name_of_Object+[i]+[j] = (object definition)
```

But this is not possible and I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

But is there a way of creating objects based on indices of a list?

Best,
Martin

(I am using the Canopy environment to do my python programming.)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to create the variables in the namespace `Name_of_Object00`, `Name_of_Object01`, `Name_of_Object02`, `Name_of_Object10`, etc...?  Otherwise, I'm not clear on what you want.

Comment: @SethMMorton That is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define these objects in a list and then you can access individual variables as li[i][j]

```
li = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    tempLi = []
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        tempLi.append((object definition))
    li.append(tempLi)
```

Comment: The problem is not accessing but I need to define an object for each combination. This I am not able to. I can use the indexes in the definition of the objects but not in defining the names.

Comment: The reason why you are getting an error with "Name_of_Object+[i]+[j] = (object definition)" is that you cannot assign the "object definition" value to the left-hand-side which is not a Python container. In the above approach, you would be creating an object for each (i,j), it is just that you would access it as an element of the list object, instead of a single object.

Answer (score 0):

we can't concatenate to an operator but we can use it an array. that is

```
Name_of_Object[i][j] = (object definition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do your assignment with an `exec` statement

```
exec("Name_of_Object{0}{1} = object declaration".format(i,j))
```

But I don't think this is a good idea because you won't be able to call your objects without an exec statement further in your program unless you specificaly want Name_of_Object01 or Name_of_Object02,...

for instance if you need to loop over your instances each time you want to do something with it you will need to write:

```
exec("Name_of_Object{0}{1}.method(...)".format(i,j))
```

So I think you should you use a multidimensional array